# How to activate a component to utilize within another application Android?

Tags: android, components

Recently, I go through the below point but I am unable to understand, how would,we activate the component to utilize within another application.I knew the process of giving package name and class name within the intent to call another application component.Please help me out to activate the component?

> your application cannot directly activate a component from another
>   application. The Android system, however, can. So, to activate a
>   component in another application, you must deliver a message to the
>   system that specifies your intent to start a particular component. The
>   system then activates the component for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's a hint- [Android Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/11/integrating-application-with-intents.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just add `android:exported="true"` to your activity, to be visible in another application  in the android Manifest file

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [Intent](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html) to ativate a component in another application.

As per the [dev guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html):

> An Intent object is a bundle of information... Principally, it can
> contain the following:
>
> Component name: The name of the component that
> should handle the intent. This field is a ComponentName object — a
> combination of the fully qualified class name of the target component
> (for example "com.example.project.app.FreneticActivity") and the
> package name set in the manifest file of the application where the
> component resides (for example, "com.example.project"). The package
> part of the component name and the package name set in the manifest do
> not necessarily have to match...

Here are some example of how to use Intents

- http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html
- http://www.droidnova.com/use-intents-to-start-other-activities,76.html